# Is it possible to block or remove a line of javascript before a webpage finishes loading?

Tags: firefox, javascript, plugins

I am looking to block or remove a line of javascript from a specific website before it finishes loading. Is it possible to do this in firefox? Any specific plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) allows you to control your web pages, including edits and deletions.  This is where I'd start first, though you'd need a bit of coding to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can block entire scripts with noscript and I think you can also change the files that load. Play with it its quite cool and very useful!

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/